# "Module not specified" error in application project to library project conversion

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to convert an android-studio application project to library project. For this, I have followed official documentation from https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert

I.e. changed

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

to

> apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

After that, it's giving "Module not specified" error in run configuration setting. I have tried syncing gradle files, invalidating and restarting android-studio, but "Module not specified" error has not been resolved.
How to resolve this error in converting application project to library project?

Answer (score 0):

It is because a library module cannot run as app.

You need to new a module(say ***newapp***) and set its buuild.gradle `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`, then edit the root settings.gradle `include 'newapp'`.

Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the aar file by running directly the gradle build task, selecting it from the gradle tasks of the app module:

[image]